# Can a dividend reinvestment plan (DRIP) and share purchase plan (SPP) be used with a TFSA?

Tags: stocks, canada, tfsa, dividend-reinvestment, share-purchase-plan

Can I put Sun Life (SLF) shares into a dividend reinvestment plan (DRIP) and share purchase plan (SPP) plan, and then put into a TFSA investment account for a family member, 5 to 10 year term?

Comment: Perhaps adding a _country_ tag, and some explanation of what the various abbreviations mean, will make your question more understandable and answerable.

Answer (score 3):

You can hold a wide variety of investments in your TFSA account, including stocks such as SLF. But if the stocks are being purchased via a company stock purchase plan, they are typically deposited in a regular margin account with a brokerage firm (a few companies may issue physical stock certificates but that is very rare these days). That account would not be a TFSA but you can perform what's called an "in-kind" transfer to move them into a TFSA that you open with either the same brokerage firm, or a different one. There will be a fee for the transfer - check with the brokerage that currently holds the stock to find out how costly that will be.

Assuming the stock gained in value while you held it outside the TFSA, this transfer will result in capital gains tax that you'll have to pay when you file your taxes for the year in which the transfer occurs. The tax would be calculated by taking the value at time of transfer, minus the purchase price (or the market value at time of purchase, if your plan allowed you to buy it at a discounted price; the discounted amount will be automatically taxed by your employer). 50% of the capital gain is added to your annual income when calculating taxes owed.

Normally when you sell a stock that has lost value, you can actually get a "capital loss" deduction that is used to offset gains that you made in other stocks, or redeemed against capital gains tax paid in previous years, or carried forward to apply against gains in future years. However, if the stock decreased in value and you transfer it, you are not eligible to claim a capital loss.

I'm not sure why you said "TFSA for a family member", as you cannot directly contribute to someone else's TFSA account. You can give them a gift of money or stocks, which they can deposit in their TFSA account, but that involves that extra step of gifting, and the money/stocks become their property to do with as they please.

Now that I've (hopefully) answered all your questions, let me offer you some advice, as someone who also participates in an employee stock purchase plan. Holding stock in the company that you work for is a **bad idea**. The reason is simple: if something terrible happens to the company, their stock will plummet and at the same time they may be forced to lay off many employees. So just at the time when you lose your job and might want to sell your stock, suddenly the value of your stocks has gone way down! So you really should sell your company shares at least once a year, and then use that money to invest in your TFSA account. You also don't want to put all your eggs in one basket - you should be spreading your investment among many companies, or better yet, buy index mutual funds or ETFs which hold all the companies in a certain index. There's lots of good info about index investing available at [Canadian Couch Potato](http://canadiancouchpotato.com/). The types of investments recommended there are all possible to purchase inside a TFSA account, to shelter the growth from being taxed.

EDIT: [Here is an article from MoneySense](http://www.moneysense.ca/columns/transferring-stocks-into-a-tfsa) that talks about transferring stocks into a TFSA. It also mentions the importance of having a diversified portfolio!